# Conflicting declarations in gtkmm headers

Tags: c++, codeblocks, gtkmm, glibmm

I'm beginning to think I need to scrap everything and redo it from scratch. 
I've been manually adding libraries from GTK and gtkmm in the codeblocks compiler settings, when I finally see something else than missing header, I get this.

```
    ||=== test, Debug ===|
   /usr/include/gdkmm-3.0/gdkmm/applaunchcontext.h|32|error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct _GdkAppLaunchContext GdkAppLaunchContext’|
   /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkapplaunchcontext.h|42|error: ‘GdkAppLaunchContext’ has a previous declaration as ‘typedef struct GdkAppLaunchContext GdkAppLaunchContext’|
   /usr/include/gdkmm-3.0/gdkmm/applaunchcontext.h|33|error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct _GdkAppLaunchContextClass GdkAppLaunchContextClass’|
   /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkapplaunchcontext.h|43|error: ‘GdkAppLaunchContextClass’ has a previous declaration as ‘typedef struct GdkAppLaunchContextClass GdkAppLaunchContextClass’|
   /usr/include/gdkmm-3.0/gdkmm/rgba.h|251|error: return type ‘Gdk::RGBATraits::CType {aka struct _GdkRGBA}’ is incomplete|
   /usr/include/gdkmm-3.0/gdkmm/rgba.h|252|error: return type ‘Gdk::RGBATraits::CType {aka struct _GdkRGBA}’ is incomplete|
   /usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm/widget.h|3890|error: ‘GdkEventTouch’ was not declared in this scope|
   /usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm/widget.h|3890|error: template argument 2 is invalid|
   ||=== Build finished: 8 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

any ideas on how I can solve this? 
also, any tips on how to add these libraries to the standard path for libraries? doing this manually for every project will be a huge pain.

Comment: Since gtkmm doesn't claim any support for Code::Blocks that I can see I would suggest using a different compiler/IDE. This page https://live.gnome.org/gtkmm/MSWindows gives instructions for various Windows enironments.

Comment: I'm working under linux though.

Comment: I should have spotted that, apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it. instead of adding the header directories under the compiler's search directories.
I added the following line:

```
    `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtkmm-3.0`
```

to other options under both compiler and linker in codeblocks. that solved all conflicts and allowed me to run my test program finally.

Comment: Where exactly did you add that line?